# Android Studio TextView Text Selection Handler Icon Position

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview, textselection

[Click here to see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3P18.png)
I want to set position of this custom right and left handlers aligned text top.Can you help me with that

Comment: Can you provide the image in the question directly instead of providing a link to it? Additionally, can you describe what you've already tried and why you have custom right and left handlers?

Comment: Stackoverflow did not let me to add image directly.My customer want that icons in design.I looked for native functions of textview but I haven't found anything

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 line in your **TextView**

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:textSelectHandle="@layout/activity_name"
```